# Cordova 4.1.2 CLI Android Build Fail Windows

Tags: java, android, apache, cordova

I am trying to install and work on cordova for the the first time. I got through all the installation steps on the cordova apache page. However, I get to the point where I need to build an android app and it never works. I get the following error (which seems to be a frequent error to cordova first-timers but no helpful review on the matter)

The identifying error lines are:

```
Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s,/c,ant,debug,-f,C:\wamp\www\hello\platforms\android\build.xml,-Dout.dir=ant-build,-Dgen.absolute.dir=ant-gen
Error: C:\wamp\www\hello\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat: Command failed with exit code 8
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\Mina\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\superspawn.js:135:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:766:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:833:5)
```

Here is the full cordova dump

```
Running command: C:\wamp\www\hello\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat 
Buildfile: C:\wamp\www\hello\platforms\android\build.xml

-set-mode-check:

-set-debug-files:

-check-env:
 [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 24.0.2
 [checkenv] Installed at C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk

-setup:
     [echo] Project Name: CordovaApp
  [gettype] Project Type: Application

-set-debug-mode:

-debug-obfuscation-check:

-pre-build:

-build-setup:
[getbuildtools] Using latest Build Tools: 21.1.2
     [echo] Resolving Build Target for CordovaApp...
[gettarget] Project Target:   Android 4.4.2
[gettarget] API level:        19
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Creating output directories if needed...
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\wamp\www\hello\platforms\android\ant-build\rsObj
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\wamp\www\hello\platforms\android\ant-build\rsLibs
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Resolving Dependencies for CordovaApp...
[dependency] Library dependencies:
[dependency] 
[dependency] ------------------
[dependency] Ordered libraries:
[dependency] 
[dependency] ------------------
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Building Libraries with 'debug'...

nodeps:

-set-mode-check:

-set-debug-files:

-check-env:
 [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 24.0.2
 [checkenv] Installed at C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk

-setup:
     [echo] Project Name: CordovaApp
  [gettype] Project Type: Android Library

-set-debug-mode:

-debug-obfuscation-check:

-pre-build:

-build-setup:
[getbuildtools] Using latest Build Tools: 21.1.2
     [echo] Resolving Build Target for CordovaApp...
[gettarget] Project Target:   Android 4.4.2
[gettarget] API level:        19
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Creating output directories if needed...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Resolving Dependencies for CordovaApp...
[dependency] Library dependencies:
[dependency] No Libraries
[dependency] 
[dependency] ------------------

-code-gen:
[mergemanifest] Found Deleted Target File
[mergemanifest] Merging AndroidManifest files into one.
[mergemanifest] Manifest merger disabled. Using project manifest only.
     [echo] Handling aidl files...
     [aidl] No AIDL files to compile.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling RenderScript files...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling Resources...
     [aapt] Found new input file
     [aapt] Generating resource IDs...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling BuildConfig class...
[buildconfig] No need to generate new BuildConfig.

-pre-compile:

-compile:
     [echo] Creating library output jar file...

-post-compile:

-obfuscate:

-dex:
     [echo] Library project: do not convert bytecode...

-crunch:
   [crunch] Crunching PNG Files in source dir: C:\wamp\www\hello\platforms\android\CordovaLib\res
   [crunch] To destination dir: C:\wamp\www\hello\platforms\android\CordovaLib\ant-build\res
   [crunch] Crunched 0 PNG files to update cache

-package-resources:
     [echo] Library project: do not package resources...

-package:
     [echo] Library project: do not package apk...

-post-package:

-do-debug:
     [echo] Library project: do not create apk...
[propertyfile] Updating property file: C:\wamp\www\hello\platforms\android\CordovaLib\ant-build\build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: C:\wamp\www\hello\platforms\android\CordovaLib\ant-build\build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: C:\wamp\www\hello\platforms\android\CordovaLib\ant-build\build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: C:\wamp\www\hello\platforms\android\CordovaLib\ant-build\build.prop

-post-build:

debug:

-code-gen:
[mergemanifest] Found Deleted Target File
[mergemanifest] Merging AndroidManifest files into one.
[mergemanifest] Manifest merger disabled. Using project manifest only.
     [echo] Handling aidl files...
     [aidl] No AIDL files to compile.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling RenderScript files...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling Resources...
     [aapt] Found Deleted Target File
     [aapt] Generating resource IDs...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling BuildConfig class...
[buildconfig] Generating BuildConfig class.

-pre-compile:
     [echo] Set jars path to: C:\wamp\www\hello\platforms\android\CordovaLib\ant-build\classes.jar

-compile:
    [javac] Compiling 3 source files to C:\wamp\www\hello\platforms\android\ant-build\classes
    [javac] warning: [options] source value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
    [javac] warning: [options] target value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
    [javac] warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
    [javac] 3 warnings

-post-compile:

-obfuscate:

-dex:
      [dex] input: C:\wamp\www\hello\platforms\android\ant-build\classes
      [dex] input: C:\wamp\www\hello\platforms\android\CordovaLib\ant-build\classes.jar
      [dex] Using Pre-Dexed classes-d5034d149c5e3b24847cc18212597ab2.jar <- C:\wamp\www\hello\platforms\android\CordovaLib\ant-build\classes.jar
      [dex] Found Deleted Target File
      [dex] Converting compiled files and external libraries into C:\wamp\www\hello\platforms\android\ant-build\classes.dex...
       [dx] Merged dex A (7 defs/2.2KiB) with dex B (209 defs/316.7KiB). Result is 216 defs/388.2KiB. Took 0.2s

-crunch:
   [crunch] Crunching PNG Files in source dir: C:\wamp\www\hello\platforms\android\res
   [crunch] To destination dir: C:\wamp\www\hello\platforms\android\ant-build\res
   [crunch] Crunched 0 PNG files to update cache

-package-resources:
     [aapt] Creating full resource package...

-package:
[apkbuilder] Current build type is different than previous build: forced apkbuilder run.
[apkbuilder] Creating CordovaApp-debug-unaligned.apk and signing it with a debug key...

BUILD FAILED
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:962: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:973: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:312: com.android.sdklib.build.ApkCreationException: Debug Certificate expired on 5/6/13 5:04 PM
    at com.android.sdklib.build.ApkBuilder.getDebugKey(ApkBuilder.java:285)
    at com.android.sdklib.build.ApkBuilder.<init>(ApkBuilder.java:392)
    at com.android.ant.ApkBuilderTask.execute(ApkBuilderTask.java:334)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.MacroInstance.execute(MacroInstance.java:396)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
    at com.android.ant.IfElseTask.execute(IfElseTask.java:124)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
    at com.android.ant.IfElseTask.execute(IfElseTask.java:124)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.MacroInstance.execute(MacroInstance.java:396)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1364)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:851)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:235)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)

Total time: 6 seconds

C:\wamp\www\hello\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s,/c,ant,debug,-f,C:\wamp\www\hello\platforms\android\build.xml,-Dout.dir=ant-build,-Dgen.absolute.dir=ant-gen
Error: C:\wamp\www\hello\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat: Command failed with exit code 8
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\Mina\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\superspawn.js:135:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:766:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:833:5)
```

Here are my relevant environment variables

```
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk
ANDROID_PLATFORM_TOOLS=C:\\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools
ANT_HOME=C:\wamp\apache-ant
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25
```

My Cordova build is 4.1.2. JDK 1.8
    Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to delete this file:

```
%USERPROFILE%/.android/debug.keystore
```

or on Linux/OS X:

```
~/.android/debug.keystore
```

It's your debug certificate, which seems to be expired.

Comment: Thank you so much Pataar! I have been struggling with this really badly. I guess this problem would appear to those who are installing cordova on an old android installation. Right? Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

#### 1)Create the app using cordova?

> cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld

Your app name is "Hello".

#### 2)Change directory to your app?

> cd hello

#### 3)Add platform on your app before build your app?

for Apple iOS:

> cordova platform add ios

for Amazon Mobile:

> cordova platform add amazon-fireos

for Android:

> cordova platform add android

for Blackberry 10:

> cordova platform add blackberry10

for Firefox OS:

> cordova platform add firefoxos

#### 4)Build your app?

Run the following command to build the project:

> cordova build

#### 5)Test the App on an Emulator or Device?

> cordova emulate android

Bold text are `cordova` commands you will run this on your CMD

Comment: Thank you prabhu. The error I received is after I followed these steps already. Except I am only building for android.